# Define object from template type

Tags: c++, templates

is there any way to define an object in a way similar to the line below???

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    T *data;
    //...   
    typedef T data_type;
};

int main() {
    A<int>::data_type a;    // ok

    A<int> obj;
    obj.data_type b;        // <-- is it possible to do something like this??
}
```

Thanks!

Massimo

Comment: decltype(obj)::data_type b; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From C++11 onwards it *is* possible:

`decltype(obj)` is evaluated at compile-time and is the *type* of `obj`. It can be used whenever a type is used.

So you could write `decltype(obj)::data_type b;`

`decltype` is a *keyword* and is particularly useful in generic programming.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`decltype` on expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype). The code for your case would be:

```
decltype(obj)::data_type b;
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine; use decltype() for c++11; you can try typeof() pre c++11
typeof() in gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct A {
  T *data;
  //...   
  typedef T data_type;
};

int main() {
  A<int>::data_type a;    // ok

  A<int> obj;
  decltype(obj)::data_type b;        // <-- is it possible to do something like this??
}
```

Comment: How would typeof() be useful pre C++11?